# How (and if) to write a single-consumer queue using the TPL?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, queue, task-parallel-library

I've heard a bunch of podcasts recently about the TPL in .NET 4.0.  Most of them describe background activities like downloading images or doing a computation, using tasks so that the work doesn't interfere with a GUI thread.

Most of the code I work on has more of a multiple-producer / single-consumer flavor, where work items from multiple sources must be queued and then processed in order.  One example would be logging, where log lines from multiple threads are sequentialized into a single queue for eventual writing to a file or database.  All the records from any single source must remain in order, and records from the same moment in time should be "close" to each other in the eventual output.

So multiple threads or tasks or whatever are all invoking a queuer:

```
lock( _queue ) // or use a lock-free queue!
{
   _queue.enqueue( some_work );
   _queueSemaphore.Release();
}
```

And a dedicated worker thread processes the queue:

```
while( _queueSemaphore.WaitOne() )
{
   lock( _queue )
   {
      some_work = _queue.dequeue();     
   }
   deal_with( some_work );
}
```

It's always seemed reasonable to dedicate a worker thread for the consumer side of these tasks.  Should I write future programs using some construct from the TPL instead?  Which one?  Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a long running Task to process items from a BlockingCollection as suggested by Wilka. Here's an example which pretty much meets your applications requirements. You'll see output something like this:

```
Log from task B
Log from task A
Log from task B1
Log from task D
Log from task C
```

Not that outputs from A, B, C & D appear random because they depend on the start time of the threads but B always appears before B1.

```
public class LogItem 
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public LogItem (string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}

public void Example()
{
    BlockingCollection<LogItem> _queue = new BlockingCollection<LogItem>();

    // Start queue listener...
    CancellationTokenSource canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task listener = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!canceller.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                LogItem item;
                if (_queue.TryTake(out item))
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Message);
            }
        },
    canceller.Token, 
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
    TaskScheduler.Default);

    // Add some log messages in parallel...
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => { _queue.Add(new LogItem("Log from task A")); },
        () => { 
            _queue.Add(new LogItem("Log from task B")); 
            _queue.Add(new LogItem("Log from task B1")); 
        },
        () => { _queue.Add(new LogItem("Log from task C")); },
        () => { _queue.Add(new LogItem("Log from task D")); });

    // Pretend to do other things...
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // Shut down the listener...
    canceller.Cancel();
    listener.Wait();
}
```

Comment: +1 for concise and useful example of TPL functionality without overengineering. I implemented this in conjunction with a ConcurrentQueue<T> in order to queue file-write operations onto one thread (multiple threads write to queue, only the listener thread reads from and processes queue items)

Comment: UPDATE: In my implementation, I noticed that this listener task with the ConcurrentQueue<T> was eating 12% of one core on an i7-870 and 25% of one core on a dual core Xeon 2.4ghz server. The while loop which perpetually calls TryDequeue was killing the CPU. This may or may not be the same case with the BlockingCollection, but I wanted to report on it... I ended up not using a Queue and using TPL instead, so in this example, every _queue.Add call would be a Task.ContinueWith() call (except the first one would be a TaskFactory.StartNew() call, in an If statement)...it worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Does using the following help reduce the cpu spin on the while?
LogItem item = _queue.Take(canceller.Token);
Console.WriteLine(item.Message);

Comment: Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502902/dequeueing-objects-from-a-concurrentqueue-in-c

Comment: we can use ConcurrentQueue instead of BlockingCollection?

Comment: WAP Guy - I don't see why not if this has the semantics you want then it should be fine.

Comment: Another way to fix the 100% CPU spin wait loop in this answer would be to use `queue.Take(Canceller.Token)` or simply make it a `foreach` loop and use `queue.CompleteAdding()` to shut it down instead.

Comment: See [MSDN: How to: Take Items from a BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997306.aspx) for canonical implementations. If using `queue.TryTake()` then **always** include a timeout or you will spin. Catch appropriate exceptions if using `queue.CompleteAdding()`, `queue.Take(cancelToken)` or `queue.TryTake(cancelToken)`.

Comment: What if I dont know when to cancel?  I.E.  I have event A fire for reason X.  There could be many reasons X, so I dont know how many will be.  But event A creates a Task to process the event.  For 10 X events, event A fires 10 times resulting in 10 tasks.  How do I execute these tasks synchronously without blocking UI thread

Answer (score 5):

I know this answer is about a year late, but take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx).

which shows how to create a LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler from the TaskScheduler class.  By limiting the concurrency to a single task, that should then process your tasks in order as they are queued via:

```
LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);

factory.StartNew(()=> 
{
   // your code
});
```

Comment: Barry, great point - see my comment to the answer by Ade Miller. I tested the listener/queue method and the TPL and found a huge performance difference making the former unacceptable as a real world solution.

Comment: I used the TPL as per my answer for similar reasons to you - file i/o locally, so I don't thrash the disk and degrade performance.

Comment: To further explain, this was not working for me.  It was resulting in same race condition I would get by just running Task t = Task.Run(()=>{... MY CODE...});.  What I did to solve my issue was to use RunSynchronously() like: Task t = new Task(()=>{.... MY CODE ...});  t.RunSynchronously();  That resolved my race condition and all task were executing synchronously.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that TPL is adequate in your use case. From my understanding the main use case for TPL is to split one huge task into several smaller tasks that can be run side by side. For example if you have a big list and you want to apply the same transformation on each element. In this case you can have several tasks applying the transformation on a subset of the list.

The case you describe doesn't seem to fit in this picture for me. In your case you don't have several tasks that do the same thing in parallel. You have several different tasks that each does is own job (the producers) and one task that consumes. Perhaps TPL could be used for the consumer part if you want to have multiple consumers because in this case, each consumer does the same job (assuming you find a logic to enforce the temporal consistency you look for).

Well, this of course is just my personnal view on the subject

Live long and prosper

Comment: +1. TPL is an intrinsic parallelism mechanism, not some reaplcement for queues etc.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371%28VS.100%29.aspx) would be handy for you. So for your code above, you could use something like (assuming `_queue` is a `BlockingCollection` instance):

```
// for your producers 
_queue.Add(some_work);
```

A dedicated worker thread processing the queue:

```
foreach (var some_work in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    deal_with(some_work);
}
```

Note: when all your producers have finished producing stuff, you'll need to call `CompleteAdding()` on `_queue` otherwise your consumer will be stuck waiting for more work.