# Dequeueing objects from a ConcurrentQueue in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hey, I'm trying to implement a ConcurrentQueue in C# for an asynchronous server.  Items are being queued as soon as a complete message is received.  To dequeue messages, I'm making a small number of threads to do the work of dequeueing and servicing the requests.  This is inadequate as each thread is using a while loop, which consumes rather a large amount of processor time, for obvious reasons.

Would anyone know of a method of dequeueing messages when required but not consuming so much processing time.

```
{
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startParsingMessages));
        t.Start();
    }

    ...
}

private void startParsingMessages()
{
    QueueContainer dequeued = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Trying");
    while (true)
    {
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out dequeued))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("processing queue");
            ProcessMessage(dequeued.socket, dequeued.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` directly, have you tried wrapping it in a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)? Then you can use `TryTake(out T, TimeSpan)` etc. I believe that's the expected use: that the concurrent collections themselves would *usually* be there just so you can select how the blocking collection will work.

That doesn't have to be the *only* use for these collections of course, but particularly for `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, the producer/consumer queue scenario is the most common one - at which point `BlockingCollection<T>` is the way to make it easy to do the right thing.

Comment: +1 You almost imply that the concurrent collections are only there to back `BlockingCollection` and I'm not sure that's true.  But you're dead on with using the `BlockingCollection` here to minimize all of the ceremony to go along with traditional producer/consumer patterns.

Comment: @Marc: I wouldn't say it's quite true to that extent, but I think that'll be the *predominant* use. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions!  I've wrapped my ConcurrentQueue in a BlockingCollection and the results are fantastic.  I'm running 20 threads concurrently to eat through the queue, with a blocking time of 0.1 seconds per thread via the TryTake(out T, TimeSpan s) method, and it's working a charm.  Request are being serviced within an appropriate time (quicker than without the concurrentqueue) and the CPU load has never been lower.

Thanks again!

Comment: @user352891: Woot! That's great to hear :)

Comment: I think this is the first decent design pattern I've read, concerning ConcurrentQueue<T>.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Is polling via TryTake the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @sgtz: Seems reasonable to me, yes.

Comment: won't this wrapping destroy the order of objects? ConcurrentQueue is described as FIFO, BlockingCollection isn't

Comment: @Offler: BlockingCollection wraps another `IProducerConsumerCollection`, defaulting to `ConcurrentQueue` if you don't specify anything else. So no, it won't destroy ordering.

Answer (score 6):

There is a pretty well know pattern in concurrent programming called Parallel Producer/Consumer pattern. This article might help resolve some of your issues. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could use a static locking object for the threads to wait on and then pulse it when something is ready to be processed.

```
static readonly object queueLock = new object();

// Threads that enqueue an object
void QueueMessage() {
  lock (queueLock) {
    queue.Enqueue(obj);
    Monitor.Pulse(queueLock);
  }
}
// Thread dequeuer
private void startParsingMessages() {
  QueueContainer dequeued = null;
  Console.WriteLine("Trying");
  while (true) {
    lock(queueLock) {
      if (!queue.TryDequeue(out dequeued)) {
        Console.WriteLine("No object to dequeue, waiting...");
        // Threads will wait here and only one will be released when .Pulse()d
        Monitor.Wait(queueLock);
        dequeued = queue.Dequeue();
      }
      if (dequeued != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("processing queue");
        ProcessMessage(dequeued.socket, dequeued.message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this can get quite complicated with the more branches you have, but the gist of it is, you lock on a common object and call `Monitor.Wait` to wait on an object to be `Pulse`d.  When this happens only one thread that was waiting on it will be released. If you enqueue a lot of objects and want them all to go, you can call `Monitor.PulseAll` which will release all threads that were waiting on the object.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion!  I implemented your suggestion and the results were very promising with a small number of requests.  However as soon as there were a large number of requests to be serviced, the time taken to respond increased dramatically.  

Again, thanks for the suggestion, it's certainly a technique I'll keep in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

The BlockingCollection solution is great. Otherwise, simply sleeping is probably good enough for most cases. It introduces a small delay in response time, and it does consume a small amount of processing time. The advantage is a more robust system that's easier to understand and less likely to fail:

```
private void startParsingMessages()
{
    QueueContainer dequeued = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Trying");
    while (true)
    {
        //As long as there is data, process it as fast as possible.
        while(queue.TryDequeue(out dequeued))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("processing queue");
            ProcessMessage(dequeued.socket, dequeued.message);
        }
        //No more data, wait 100 ms before checking again
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it _more robust_ than `BlockingCollection` but the idea of sleeping during _Idle_ state is a good throttling pattern that is commonly used. Depending on how critical it is to process the data in real-time and how many of these processes have been instantiated concurrently, you might also introduce an _incremental back-off_ sleep pattern, where the sleep time increases for each iteration where no iotems were processed.

Comment: I fully agree BlockingCollection is at least as robust in this case. In general, I wanted to show this pattern because it comes up often, and I've had way better luck over the years with the sleeping like this instead of some sort of signaling mechanism.

Comment: Sorry to be critical @Dwayne I actually prefer this pattern for almost all of my simple queue-based processing logic, I was just commenting on the language you used. What's not obvious is the magic `Sleep(100)` and some ideas on how to use it. and how it affects things. Especially because you're up against an 11 year old post from Jon, it means we should put in more effort to sell this to the next reader.