# Most Efficient way to create list of all existing items in ConcurrentQueue at certain timestamp

Tags: c#

I have to maintain information logs , these logs can be written from many threads concurrently, but when I need them I am using only one thread to dequeue it that takes break of around 5 seconds between dequeueing the collection.

Following is the code I've written to Dequeue it.

```
if (timeNotReached)
{
   InformationLogQueue.Enqueue(informationLog);
}
else
{
    int currentLogCount = InformationLogQueue.Count;
            var informationLogs = new List<InformationLog>();
            for (int i = 0; i < currentLogCount; i++)
            {
                InformationLog informationLog1;
                InformationLogQueue.TryDequeue(out informationLog1);
                informationLogs.Add(informationLog1);
            }
    WriteToDatabase(informationLogs);
}
```

After dequeueing I am passing it to LINQ's insert method that requires List of InformationLog to insert to database.

Is this the correct way or is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: What's the point of using a `ConcurrentQueue` if you set the reference to a new instance everytime you dequeue somthing?

Comment: why don't you just use the ConcurrentQueue directly from that one thread?  Why are you dumping all items to a list first?

Comment: After dequeueing I am passing it to LINQ's insert method that requires List of InformationLog to insert to database.

Comment: If I read this right you're not Dequeueing at all but just copying the elements ?

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryDequeue` _attempts_ to remove, so you should check the return value to see if an element was removed (`informationLog1` might might be `null` or `default(T)`). See @[Eren Ersönmez's extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12259755/63011) if you are trying to dequeue all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using the  `ConcurrentQueue<T>` via a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502902/dequeueing-objects-from-a-concurrentqueue-in-c-sharp).

---

Somthing like this,

```
private BlockingCollection<InformationLog> informationLogs = 
    new BlockingCollection<InformationLog>(new ConcurrentQueue<InformationLog>);
```

Then on your consumer thread you can do

```
foreach(var log in this.informationLogs.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // process consumer logs 1 by 1. 
}
```

---

Okay, here is an answer for cosuming mutiple items. On the consuming thread do this,

```
InformationLog nextLog;
while (this.informationLogs.TryTake(out nextLog, -1))
{
    var workToDo = new List<informationLog>();
    workToDo.Add(nextLog);

    while(this.informationLogs.TryTake(out nextLog))
    {
        workToDo.Add(nextLog);
    }

    // process workToDo, then go back to the queue.
}
```

The first while loop takes items from the queue with an infinite wait time, I'm assuming that once adding is complete on the queue, i.e [`CompleteAdding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) is called, this call will return `false`, without a delay, once the queue is empty.

The inner while loop takes items with a 50 millisecond timeout, this could be adjusted for you needs. Once the queue is empty it will return `false`, then the batch of work can be processed.

Comment: does BlockingCollection intializes with the existing concurrent queue, and copies the queued items to it and dequeue it from the concurrent queue, so that next time when I dequeue it should not be there

Comment: I don't want to block the call , if no item is there , no problem.

Comment: The `BlockingCollection` should be used to wrap `ConcurrentQueue`, `ConcurrentBag` and `ConcurrentStack` or any other implementors of `IProducerConsumer`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx

Comment: Won't you want to dequeue in a loop, or "consume"?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` directly in a Linq statement via an extension method like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> DequeueExisting<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> queue)
{
    T item;
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
        yield return item;
}
```

This would save you from having to continuously allocate new `List<T>` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` objects.