# Windows service running multiple processes using Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a **C# Windows Service** that has a Timer that checks every 10 seconds a "flag" in my `SQL Table` for any Process Pending To Execute.

So right now I have inside my Windows Service:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {

    // flag so the process is only executed one at a time.
    if (!_isProcessBusy) {

        RunProcess();

    }
}

private void RunProcessSync() {

    _isProcessBusy = true;

    // ... here all the code for doing the internal process ...


    // when process is Done then change the flag so a new process can be executed
    _isProcessBusy = false;

}
```

Now I need to let the Windows Service Runs multiple threads of the same process, So if in my `SQL Table` I have 3 processed to execute then I will let the service run the 3 at the same time.

I was thinking to use `System.Threading.Tasks` library but don't know if this is the right approach or maybe there is something easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a question here but:

Yes. You can use Tasks, and async-await, and Parallel. The simplest option here would probably be to use [`Parallel.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Parallel.Invoke(new Action[] 
{
    () => RunProcess(1), 
    () => RunProcess(2), 
    () => RunProcess(3)
});
```

This will internally use the TaskParallelLibrary, but it's much simpler. more here: [Parallel.Invoke() vs. Explicit Task Management](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/07/10/9828076.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I never know how many proceeses there service is executing. What I need is to add into an array each Task when the timer fires and finds a pending process to execute.

Comment: @VAAA that's ok. it was just an example. Parallel.Invoke accepts an array of Actions. Send it an array with as many as you need.

Comment: So, on my timer_Elapsed function I can add a new Instance of my process to that array right? but do I have to Invoke again?

Comment: @VAAA why add and not just fire how many processes you have waiting using invoke again.

Comment: ok ok.. going to read more about this becuase its not 100% clear. Thanks a lot

Comment: @VAAA if you actually have an item to to process then maybe TPL Dataflow would be easier for you. Create an ActionBlock, give it a func, set the degree of parallelism and start posting to it.

Comment: I think the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293976/how-and-if-to-write-a-single-consumer-queue-using-the-tpl

Comment: @VAAA that's for .net 4.0, before microsoft released TPL Dataflow., I strongly recommend using that instead of an example online.

Comment: How can I convert the example online to TPL Dataflow? Is that hard? Because I just tried the example and works great

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52696/discussion-between-i3arnon-and-vaaa)

Answer (score -3):

You can create backgroundWorker to make this background processing.
(BackgroundWorker is only a "warpper" for thread clases).

Best regards

Comment: Why would you suggest BGW over the TPL library as the OP suggested?